# how to rescan m4 data for recursive macro inplace substitution

Tags: c, bash, unix, macros, m4

I have this very simple code.

```
define(`S',`some')
define(`T',`thing')
define(`D',`doing')
define(`something',`st_todo') 
define(`st_tododoing',`done!')
S`'T 
OR 
S()T()
```

the actual end result is

```
something 
OR 
something
```

but expected recursive substitution result as

```
st_todo
```

how I can rescan the code to the input again ?

maybe the "indir", But its A crooked nasty solution:

```
indir(S()`'T()`'D())
```

the result is:

```
--NOTHING--
```

maybe the so called command "divert", can make the output, recycled to input ?

of course the reviews says it is "inplace macro substitution",
BUT the result are different.

of course we can use "C" language primitive macro solution. EG:

```
define(`concat',`$1$2$2$4$5')
```

BUT this "concat" "solution", will increase the code NESTING complexity, in a large code reconstruction. EG:

```
concat(concat(S1,T1),concat(S2,T2,more1,more2,...))
```

WHAT if we have "concat" of 10 words OR more OR with conditionals "ifelse" ?.

**M4 concept is beyond the old "C" preprocessor!**

the real solution must come from the macro "inside core system"

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

M4 does rescan. However, the empty string `` `' `` ends the preceding token, and thus prevents `some` and `thing` from being recognised as a single token.

Instead, concatenate the macro expansions using another macro:

```
define(`concat',`$1$2')
define(`S',`some')
define(`T',`thing')
define(`something',`st_todo') 
concat(S,T)
```

```
$ m4<<"EOF"
> define(`concat',`$1$2')dnl        
> define(`S',`some')dnl
> define(`T',`thing')dnl
> define(`something',`st_todo')dnl
> concat(S,T)
> EOF
st_todo
```

Comment: the result of S()T  => someT .

Comment: @contenta: Oops. OK, a more complicated solution.

Comment: Which triggers another question: why does `S()T` not expand the T?  After m4 parses the final `)`, that macro expansion is complete.  It should read `T` and expand it.

Comment: THIS IS "C" primitive macro solution! this "concat" "solution", make it very complex, in a large code reconstruction. M4 concept is beyond "C" preprocessor!!!. WHAT if  we have "concat" of 10  words ?. the real solution must be in the macro "core system".

Comment: @contenta I don't understand your comment.  But note that rather than the `concat` that rici uses, you could use the builtin `indir` and write `indir(S[]T)`.  (I changequoted to [] to avoid SO comment markup).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: After `S()` expands to `some`, the scan is reset to where the `S` was encountered, so the input is now `someT`. That's a single token, and it has no definition. With the original `S[]T`, after the substitution of `S` the input was `some[]T`; after resetting the scan, m4 sees the token `some`, an empty string, and the token `T`. It expands `T` to `thing` and then resets the scan to where the `T` started.

Comment: @contenta: if you read through the [Gnu m4 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.15/html_node/index.html) you'll see that a large number of the documented macros are not built-in.this includes `join`, which is a general form of my little `concat`, allowing a delimiter and any number of arguments. The fact that it is possible to write such a macro shows the difference with the C preprocessor: m4 has recursion, conditionals and loops. But it doesn't free you from writing (or finding) utility macros.

Comment: Somewhere I read that there is some PRECEDENCE. the quote sequence (`'), are processed AFTER expansions layer, and not BEFOR.  even in "C" quotes are processed LAST.